# How to avoid While Loop in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know I should try to avoid while loop in sql but I could not get it done, can someone please suggest a better way to achieve same result without using while loop. Here is my code -

```
begin transaction

declare @count int;
set @count = 1;

declare @Id bigint;
set @Id = 3781543256;

while @count <=35000

begin

INSERT INTO [Table_name]
           ([Column1]
           ,[Column2]
           ,[Column3]
           ,[Column4]
           ,[Column5])
     VALUES
           (7,
           @Id,
           '20130909 16:42:43.157',
           0,
           NEWID())

set @Id = @Id+1; 

set @count = @count+1;
end
```

Comment: Basically - the avoidance of "loop" in SQL is if something needs to run/query often and perform well. If it is something you run rarely or "once in a while to set up data", it is okay to have loops - and in this case, I hope it's not something you'll need to run often, so why not just keep the loop?

Comment: @Jesuraja  I have edited my question, actually -@nodeID is Id.

Comment: 5 Columns and 7 Values?

Comment: @user3581461 The proposed edit was rejected by 3 auditers so it didn't go through. I went in an re-added your changes. Can you verify that I did not mess it up?

Comment: @ivarni Can you please confirm which changes you wanted in it?

Comment: Ah, I might not have been clear enough. There was a rejected edit on the accepted answer that adjusted the number of value in the select. I re-applied that edit and I just wanted to know if the answer still looks correct. So basically, if the answer matches the question then no action is required :)

Comment: @ivarni Answer I accepted looks fine and you are right that answer  is not like I can straight copy and paste into my code and it will work right away. I had to make some changes though, but concept of the answer was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [Table_name] (
    [Column1]
   ,[Column2]
   ,[Column3]
   ,[Column4]
   ,[Column5]
)
SELECT TOP 35000
       7
      ,@Id + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY objects1.object_id)
      ,'20130909 16:42:43.157'
      ,0
      ,NEWID()
FROM sys.objects AS objects1
     CROSS JOIN sys.objects AS objects2
```

Comment: Just out of interest: what is the `CROSS JOIN` for?

Comment: @MP24, just an ansi version of a comma in this case (i.e. cartesian product). I just think it is more readable to explicitly say CROSS JOIN. Or did you mean why it is there at all? sys.objects usually contains a couple of thousand rows. The CROSS join ensures we get at least 37000 rows

Answer (score 3):

You need a numbers table. It is handy to have around anyway. Assuming you have it, you can generate the set of rows you want to insert and do it in one go:

```
INSERT ...
SELECT 7, Numbers.ID - 1 + 3781543256, ..., NEWID()
FROM Numbers
WHERE Numbers.ID BETWEEN 1 AND @count
```

Shorter, less error prone and faster. Depending on the row count and schema this can be faster by multiple orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a recursive cte to get a list of 35000 rows...

```
WITH cte1 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id
    UNION ALL SELECT id + 1 FROM cte1
    WHERE id < 1000 
),
cte2 AS 
(
    SELECT id FROM cte1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id + 1000 FROM cte2
    WHERE cte2.id <= 34000 --(the number of rows you want - 1000)
)
INSERT INTO [Table_name]
           ([Column1]
           ,[Column2]
           ,[Column3]
           ,[Column4]
           ,[Column5]
           ,[Column6]
           ,[Column7]
           ,[Column8])
SELECT
    7,
    @id + id,
    1.1,
    0,
    '20130909 16:42:43.157',
    '20130910 16:42:43.157',
    0,
    NEWID()
FROM cte2 
ORDER BY id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Note - split into 2 CTES as you can only have a maximum recursion limit of 32767 in a single cte. The default recursion limit is 100 - hence the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)`

I've done a quick test of the SELECT part of this, and it is very fast - less than a second.